NVIDIA Jetson Orin FastAI2 model optimization with TensorRT and Torch2TRT incorrect Batch size
I have a Jetson Orin with the latest version of Jetpack 6.0 with CUDA 12 running on Ubuntu 22.04.
I have installed PyTorch and it has CUDA support installed:
Python 3.10.12 (main, Sep 11 2024, 15:47:36) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> 
>>> device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
>>> print(f"Using device: {device}")
Using device: cuda

I am using tensorrt to optimize my Fastai 2.0 model:
>>> import torch2trt
>>> import tensorrt
>>> print(tensorrt.__version__)
8.6.2

I optimize the model like so:
# Parameters
detect_batch_size = 8  # Set the batch size to 8
global_win_h = 200     # Example height
global_win_w = 200     # Example width

# Create input tensor with batch size of 8
x = torch.ones((detect_batch_size, 3, global_win_h, global_win_w)).cuda()

# Create a custom logger to suppress warnings
class CustomLogger(trt.Logger):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(trt.Logger.ERROR)  # Set to ERROR to suppress warnings

# Create an instance of the custom logger
custom_logger = CustomLogger()

def load_cnn_model(logger, should_use_tensor_rt=True):
    '''
    This function loads the CNN model and returns it

    :param: logger - object to log with
    :param: should_use_tensor_rt - boolean indicating whether or not we should use NVIDIA TensorRT
    :return: tuple - learner model and classes to detect with
    '''

    # Load CNN Module
    model_load_time_start = time.time()

    # Use CUDA
    use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
    device = torch.device("cuda" if use_cuda else "cpu")
    logger.info(f"Should use CUDA: {use_cuda}")
    default_device(use=use_cuda)

    # Load the learner
    logger.info(f"Loading model now on platform: {platform.system()} ...")
    platform_designator = platform.system()
    if platform_designator == 'Linux':
        logger.info(f"Platform is {platform_designator}, changing windows path now ...")
        pathlib.WindowsPath = pathlib.PosixPath
    learner = load_learner("JetsonNanoFaceTrackingTrainAndTest/fast_ai_trained_models/face.pkl", cpu=False)
    classes = learner.dls.vocab
    logger.info(f"Classes are: {classes} ...")
    learner.model.to(device)
    learner.model.eval()

    # Optimize for tensorrt
    logger.info(f"Checking if we should use TensorRT: {should_use_tensor_rt} ...")
    if should_use_tensor_rt:

        # Check if optimized model already exists
        opt_model = Path(tensor_rt_optimized_model)
        logger.info(f"Checking for optimization model: {tensor_rt_optimized_model} ...")
        if not opt_model.exists():

            logger.info("Optimized model does not exist ...")

            # Convert model to half precision
            #learner.model = learner.model.half()

            learner.dls.to(device='cuda')
            learner.model.to(device='cuda')

            try:

                logger.info("Optimizing model for TensorRT ...")
                learner = torch2trt(learner.model, [x], logger=custom_logger) # Use custom logger to disable warnings
                logger.info("Done optimizing model ...")

                logger.info(f"Saving optmized model: {tensor_rt_optimized_model} ...")
                torch.save(learner.state_dict(), tensor_rt_optimized_model)

            except Exception as err:
                logger.error(f"Error: Failed to create optimized tensorrt model ...")
                sys.exit(1)

        else:

            logger.info(f"Loading existing optmized TensorRT model: {tensor_rt_optimized_model} ...")
            learner = TRTModule()
            learner.load_state_dict(torch.load(tensor_rt_optimized_model))

    # Measure load time
    model_load_time_end = time.time()
    logger.info(f"Model Loading Time Elapsed: {model_load_time_end - model_load_time_start}")

    # Return the model and the classes expected to detect
    return (learner, classes)

The code where the model is loaded is here (up until the process_image function call) - everything else after that call is just for displaying the inferred frame:
def detect_people():

    # Load the model and return the model and the classes
    (learner, classes) = load_cnn_model(logger, should_use_tensor_rt)

    # Start a capturing thread
    frame_queue = Queue(maxsize=3)
    capture_thread = Thread(target=capture_frames, args=(logger, frame_queue, proc_queue))
    capture_thread.start()
    logger.info("Waiting for camera to start ...")
    time.sleep(1)

    # Loop and get frames to process
    global captured_frame
    frame_cnt = 0

    # Empty cuda cache
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()

    # Define the thread to process frames with
    proc_thread = None

    # Measure frame processing time
    start_time = time.time()
    
    # Track the fps rate
    fps = 0.0

    # Capture continuously
    while True:

        # Log the prints
        frame_cnt = frame_cnt + 1
        logger.debug(f"Grabbing new frame now: {frame_cnt} ...")

        # Capture a frame
        original_image = frame_queue.get()
        logger.debug(f"Got frame: {original_image} {original_image.size}")
        display_image = np.array(original_image)
        image = np.array(original_image)

        # Check if detection should exit
        exit_results = proc_queue.get()
        logger.debug(f"Checking exit results now: {exit_results.get('should_exit')}")
        try:
            if exit_results.get("should_exit") == True:
                logger.info("Exiting detection now ...")
                sys.exit(0)
        finally:
            proc_queue.put(exit_results)

        # Wait for frames to begin streaming
        if not original_image:
            logger.warning("Warning: No frames from camera yet ...")
            time.sleep(1)
            continue

        # Submit the job to a thread
        logger.debug(f"Using learner: {learner}")

        # Use a thread task to do frame work
        should_remove_rects = True
        if not proc_thread or not proc_thread.is_alive():
            proc_thread = Thread(target=process_image, args=(logger, learner, classes, image, proc_queue,))
            proc_thread.start()
        if proc_thread.is_alive():
            logger.debug("Processing thread is already running ...")
            should_remove_rects = False

I can successfully load the optimized model and then I try to infer with the following code on my dataset with batch inference (most of the function displayed here):
def process_image(logger, learner, classes, frame, proc_queue):
    '''
    Process an image

    :param: logger - printer
    :param: learner - model to predict with
    :param: classes - classes to detect for
    :param: frame - frame to process
    :param: proc_queue - queue to put results in
    '''

    try:

        # Capture a frame
        # (original_image, image, original_width, original_height) = capture_frame_and_format_image(logger, incoming_image)
        original_width = desired_camera_frame_width
        original_height = desired_camera_frame_height

        # Store all images and meta data for each crop point
        image_list_to_infer = []
        image_list_meta_data = []

        # Define preprocess transforms for image list
        preprocess = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize(global_win_w),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
        ])

        # Loop over the image pyramid
        for resized_image_from_pyramid in pyramid(frame, scale=1.5):

            logger.debug("Working on new pyramid image ...")

            # Start the stopwatch / counter
            t1_start = perf_counter()

            # If the resized_image_from_pyramid image is smaller than window, bail
            if resized_image_from_pyramid.shape[1] < global_win_w or resized_image_from_pyramid.shape[0] < global_win_h:
                logger.warning(f"Warning: Resized image is smaller than window ...")
                break

            # Calculate Ratios for current resized_image_from_pyramid image
            ratio_x = (original_width / resized_image_from_pyramid.shape[1])
            ratio_y = (original_height / resized_image_from_pyramid.shape[0])

            logger.debug(f"Ratio: {ratio_x} / {ratio_y}")

            # Adjust the detection window
            win_h = global_win_h
            win_w = global_win_w
            if float(ratio_x) > 1.0:
                win_h = math.ceil(global_win_h * 0.6)
                win_w = math.ceil(global_win_w * 0.6)

            # If image is too small - bail
            if ratio_x > 3.0:
                logger.info(f"Image ratio reached floor: {ratio_x} - bailing now ...")
                break

            # Generate the set of windows, with a winH-pixel max window size and X% overlap
            logger.debug("Generating set of windows now ...")
            overlap_windows = random.uniform(overlap_windows_min, overlap_windows_max)
            windows = sw.generate(resized_image_from_pyramid, sw.DimOrder.HeightWidthChannel, win_h, overlap_windows)

            # Do stuff with the generated windows
            for window_data in windows:

                # Define the window size and extract the window
                x = window_data.x
                y = window_data.y
                logger.debug(f"Window index: {window_data.indices()} {x}/{y}")
                window = resized_image_from_pyramid[window_data.indices()]

                # If the window does not meet our desired window size, ignore it
                if window_data.h != win_h or window_data.w != win_w:
                    logger.info(
                        f"Warning: Window does not meet our desired window size: {window_data.h}/{win_h} | {window_data.w}/{win_w} ...")
                    break

                # Convert to PIL image and store in inference list for batch processing
                window = cv2.cvtColor(window.astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                img_pil = Image.fromarray(window.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
                logger.debug(f"Before image size: {img_pil.size}")
                a_channel = Image.new('L', img_pil.size, 255)  # 'L' 8-bit pixels, black and white
                #img_pil.putalpha(a_channel)
                #logger.debug(f"After image size: {img_pil.size}")
                image_list_to_infer.append(img_pil)

                # Store the meta data as well for each PIL image to draw rectangles appropriately
                image_list_meta_data.append({"window_data": window_data, "ratio_x": ratio_x, "ratio_y": ratio_y})

            # Do not do pyramid
            if not should_do_image_pyramid:
                logger.debug(f"Should not do image pyramid: {should_do_image_pyramid} - bailing now ...")
                break

        # Get the last image
        last_image = image_list_to_infer[-1]

        logger.info(f"Number of images to infer from: {len(image_list_to_infer)}")

        # Pad the list of images to be a multiple of the detection batch size
        while len(image_list_to_infer) % detect_batch_size != 0:
            image_list_to_infer.append(last_image)

        # Create the custom dataset
        infer_dataset = InferenceDataset(image_list_to_infer, augmentations=preprocess)

        logger.info(f"Creating data loader now: {len(image_list_to_infer)} | {infer_dataset} | {len(infer_dataset)} ...")

        # Create a DataLoader for batching
        infer_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(infer_dataset,
                                                   detect_batch_size,
                                                   shuffle=True,
                                                   num_workers=1,
                                                   pin_memory=True)

        logger.info(f"Infer loader size is: {infer_loader}")

        # Perform batch inference
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        start_inference = time.time()
        with torch.no_grad():

            # Put the model into inference mode
            accumulated_output = []
            logger.debug("Setting inference mode now ...")
            infer_counter = 0
            with torch.inference_mode():
                for data in infer_loader:
                    data = data.cuda()
                    logger.debug(f"Calling learner now: {data} ...")
                    logger.debug(f"Learner is: {learner}")

                    # Infer the class
                    #output = learner.model(data)

                    infer_counter = infer_counter + 1
                    logger.info(f"Inference counter: {infer_counter}")

                    # TesnorTRT Requires this syntax
                    output = learner(data)

                    logger.debug(f"Done calling learner: {output} ...")
                    for tensor_output in output.data.cpu():
                        accumulated_output.append(tensor_output)

        # Time the inference work
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        end_inference = time.time()
        logger.info(f"Inference time: {end_inference - start_inference} | [{len(accumulated_output)}]")

        # Iterate and calculate probability and classes
        for predicted_index, predicted_result in enumerate(accumulated_output):

            # Calculate probs and classes for classification
            prob = nnf.softmax(predicted_result, dim=0)
            prob_list = prob.tolist()
            top_p, top_class = prob.topk(1, dim=0)
            probability = top_p.tolist()[0]

            class_name = classes[top_class][0]
            if class_name.lower() != "negative":
                logger.info(f"Probability: {probability} | {class_name.lower()}")

The warning is printed when the following line in this previous function is called:
output = learner(data)

The inference fails and I get the following message on the console:
[10/19/2024-15:22:12] [TRT] [E] 3: [executionContext.cpp::validateInputBindings::2103] Error Code 3: API Usage Error (Parameter check failed at: runtime/api/executionContext.cpp::validateInputBindings::2103, condition: profileMaxDims.d[i] >= dimensions.d[i]. Supplied binding dimension [8,3,200,200] for bindings[0] exceed min ~ max range at index 0, maximum dimension in profile is 1, minimum dimension in profile is 1, but supplied dimension is 8

I am unable to figure out how to solve this issue. I believe in the original creation of the optimized model, I did set the batch to be '8'. However, I'm still seeing this issue.
How can I fix this?

Once again, we have incomplete code -- you show us load_cnn_model but you don't show all the code for that function, and you don't show where where it is called, just the identical partial code from your previous question, where learner was apparently a FastAI object, whereas now is is apparently a TensorRT object. Could you please post the actual code which is producing learner object and the error, because what is in your question clearly ins't complete

Apologies for the incomplete code examples. I have updated the question with more complete functions.
